# Android app is supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I am trying to upload my app but I get this error : " Android app is supported by 0 devices ".
[UPLOAD NEW APK TO PRODUCTION - SUMMARY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNxx9.png)

This is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="il.shenkar.tom.tasker">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.example.tomgoldberg.tasker.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.tomgoldberg.tasker.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="il.shenkar.tom.tasker.TaskerApplication"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="il.shenkar.tom.tasker.splashFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="il.shenkar.tom.tasker.NavigationDrawer" />


        <!-- Parse auth meta data -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="OHB5A7s1EGk1uqQUOk0gc6H5qRxgxDE2ziXfCW4T" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="5OuYRnc75VIJXL3flRASViUzpgGz8Vb4jM2xiD2O" />

        <!--GCM receiver-->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.example.tomgoldberg.tasker.gcm"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--GCM listener-->
        <service android:name="il.shenkar.tom.tasker.gcm.GcmMessageReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!--GCM register-->
        <service
            android:name="il.shenkar.tom.tasker.gcm.InstanceIdService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- Google analytics receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Google analytics Service -->
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <!-- Google analytics campaign receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Google analytics campaign service -->
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me how to set compatibility for several devices; I have to publish it today for school assignment.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this-

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

instead of -

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
```

Comment: Great! it works! now it gives me all kinds of devices.